# Joining Tables based on data sets with different column names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How do I join multiple tables when Table A has column CX_String_4 and Table B has column Details?  The Details column has a string that includes a number that will match what is in colunn CX_

I've tried a full join, and my result don't yield anything. Its a blank screen.

```
Full Outer Join PVXMIHS ON PVXME.CX_STRING_4=SUBSTRING(Convert(varchar(318),PVXMIHS.DETAILS),78,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Details column has a string that includes a number that will match
>   what is in colunn CX_

What you are proposing is a wild card or fuzzy match join **if you don't know the exact position of your value in the details column**. For that, you'll want to use `LIKE` which you can [read about in the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
FULL OUTER JOIN PVXMIHS ON PVXMIHS.DETAILS LIKE '%' + PVXME.CX_STRING_4 + '%'
```

This would match when the `CX_STRING_4` is anywhere in the `DETAILS` column. If you are certain you know where the value would be located with in the `DETAILS` column, then your `SUBSTRING` method would work (assuming you used the right start position and length).

Comment: I've tried this string and it works. I didn't use my substring statement. The results yielded the expectation. Thank you.